# Can't run app on Android device

Tags: android, eclipse, testing

I just started having problems running my app on my Asus TF103c. I have tried launching it from Eclipse.

```
[2014-12-24 14:29:58 - QuikFormCalcLite] Android Launch!
[2014-12-24 14:29:58 - QuikFormCalcLite] adb is running normally.
[2014-12-24 14:29:58 - QuikFormCalcLite] No Launcher activity found!
[2014-12-24 14:29:58 - QuikFormCalcLite] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2014-12-24 14:29:58 - QuikFormCalcLite] Performing sync
[2014-12-24 14:29:59 - QuikFormCalcLite] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2014-12-24 14:30:05 - QuikFormCalcLite] Uploading QuikFormCalcLite.apk onto device 'E7OKCY053292'
[2014-12-24 14:30:05 - QuikFormCalcLite] Installing QuikFormCalcLite.apk...
[2014-12-24 14:30:09 - QuikFormCalcLite] Success!
[2014-12-24 14:30:09 - QuikFormCalcLite] \QuikFormCalcLite\bin\QuikFormCalcLite.apk installed on device
[2014-12-24 14:30:09 - QuikFormCalcLite] Done!
```

I checked in my tablet's apps submenu in the settings and I see it there, but not in the normal apps menu that you access from the home screen. It also doesn't ever launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was that I hadn't defined a starting activity in the manifest - for the starting activity:

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name ="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting android adb and eclipse, try reconnecting usb cable of your device. If you have the latest version of apk. uploaded on the device, it doesn't allways automatically launch (just click on icon on your tablet).

Comment: Are you installing your app on correct device? From logcat it looks like it was installed somewhere. To change target device (in eclipse) you can go to project -> right click -> run as -> run configuration -> target: check always prompt and UNCHECK use same device for future launches. -> click Apply -> Run